# Android studio: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

Im running android studio 4.1.2
im trying to run this transaction:

QuestionDao.kt

```
  @Transaction
    suspend fun getRandomRN(num: Int):List<Question>{
     val result = getRandomWrongOrNotAnsweredQuestionsByCount(num)
        val last = getLastQuizNumber()

        val newResult = mutableListOf<Question>()

        result?.forEachIndexed{ index,element ->
            element.status=0
            element.quiz_number = last+1
            newResult[index] = element  // this is line 91
        }

        result?.let { updateQuestions(newResult) }
        return newResult
    }
```

running app throw error:

```
com.example.android.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
    Process: com.example.android.myapplication, PID: 25245
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:453)
        at com.example.android.webpooyeshelevatorquize.data.QuestionDao$DefaultImpls.getRandomRN(QuestionDao.kt:91)
```

`QuestionDao.kt:91` is `newResult[index] = element`.
BTW the context is `Dispachers.IO`

Comment: Well it says there: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0. You are using an instance of ArrayList, so you should use newResult.add(index, element) instead of newResult[index] = element. Just check if its .add(index, element) or .add(element, index).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `newResult` list is empty, you cannot use `newResult[index] = element` to add new elements to it. Use `newResult += element` or `newResult.add(emenent)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to access the index of the array while you have not initialized any element to it.
Initialize like this  newResult.add(i)